# How to implement WebApi custom model binder

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, custom-model-binder

I am implementing custom model binder. I researched how to do it and found out that in case of WebApi I need to implement `IModelBinder` interface.

My implementation looks like this:

```
public class ModelBaseBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if ((bindingContext.Model is MyModel))
        {
            //my code here

            controller.InitModel(model);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

I am just not sure if my implenentaton is complete. Do I need to call any default WebApi `BindModel` in order my custom implementation work?

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain of this implementation as I haven't tried it before. The mechanism with which I have applied to custom model binders is set the Model to an instance of my model class using the bindingContext.Model property.

ex). bindingContext.Model = new Foo();

To get the custom model binder to function in the configuration it is necessary to either use a ModelBinder attribute next to the action parameter, apply the model binder attribute to the model class, or create a parameter binding rule. Applying the model binder attribute to the action method parameter adds some flexibility into where the model binder is used and is a straightforward approach

```
  public IHttpActionResult FooAction([ModelBinder(BinderType=typeof(mymodelbinder))]Foo myFoo) { }
```