# The type does not implement the IModelBinder interface. Parameter name: binderType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have implemented [custom model binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274044/how-to-implement-webapi-custom-model-binder/32276996#32276996) for my WebApi project

```
using WebApi.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;

namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class ModelBaseBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if ((bindingContext.Model is MyModel))
            {
                //my code here

                controller.InitModel(model);

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason in `Global.asax.cs` in line `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`I am getting an error that: `The type does not implement the IModelBinder interface. Parameter name: binderType`.[image]

my `Global.asax.cs` is looking like that:

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();            
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.BindParameter(typeof(ModelBase), new ModelBaseBinder());
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

I am guessing that for some reason MVC is looking for `System.Web.ModelBinding.IModelBinder` but in case of WebApi I have `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder` implementaton insteard.

Do you have an idea how can I fix that?

**UPDATE:**

I find out that if i comment this method on my controller:

```
public void Post([FromBody]MyModel model)
        {
            //my code here
        }
```

Than I am not getting the error above. 
But still cant understand why I an getting such issue.

Here is my models details

```
public class MyModel : ModelBase
    {
    }

[ModelBinder(typeof(ModelBaseBinder))]
public class ModelBase
    {
    }
```

Comment: Is is possible that you've got mismatched assembly references between some of your projects, or between things inside your project? I imagine that MVC changed the namespace of IModelBinder from one version to the next, so if your references don't match up, or if some pieces of your web.config are still referring to the old version, I could see that causing an issue like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Verify if the *ModelBinderAttribute* on your model is the one from [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.modelbinderattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) or [System.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

There are implementations of *IModelBinder* in both ([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.modelbinding.imodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx) and [System.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx)) and your attribute match the namespace with your binder